# lambda expression used for callback function failed when I try to caputre [this],why?

Tags: c++, lambda

I need to use a DLL library,which give me a callback function defined as follow:

```
typedef void  ( __stdcall *PAmsRouterNotificationFuncEx)( long nEvent );
```

And the function used to regist the callback function given is:

```
bool RigisterStatusMonitorFunc(PAmsRouterNotificationFuncEx fpFuncAMS);
```

I try to call it like this(In a button processing function):

```
auto fpTc2RouterCall = [](LONG nReason){
    switch (nReason)
    {
    case AMSEVENT_ROUTERSTOP:
        ...
        break;
    case AMSEVENT_ROUTERSTART:
        ...
        break;
    case AMSEVENT_ROUTERREMOVED:
        ...
        break;
    default:
        ...
        break;
    }
};
…… ……

RigisterStatusMonitorFunc(fpTc2RouterCall);  //It works.
```

But when I add [this] in the caputure list，it does NOT work!Why?

```
auto fpTc2RouterCall = [this](LONG nReason){
    switch (nReason)
    {
    case AMSEVENT_ROUTERSTOP:
        ...
        StopAMS();   //Member function of this class,I need call it in the lambda expression.
        break;
    case AMSEVENT_ROUTERSTART:
        ...
        break;
    case AMSEVENT_ROUTERREMOVED:
        ...
        break;
    default:
        ...
        break;
    }
};
…… ……

RigisterStatusMonitorFunc(fpTc2RouterCall);  //It doesn't works!
```

If I add [this],it says error in VS2013:
1 IntelliSense: does not exist appropriate conversion function for the "[]void lambda (nReason LONG) ->void" to "PAmsRouterNotificationFuncEx"  f:\Study\omsPrinter.cpp 280

It seems strange,can anyone tell me why?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Because stateless lambdas decay to function pointers, while stateful do not. When you capture `this`, you turn your lambda into stateful, because created *closure* needs to store the pointer in it. When you capture nothing, closure does not need to store anything, and it may be treated the same way as a free-standing function.

Comment: Thank you very much, Mikhail. when I post this question in my domestic forum,Nobody can give me an answer.
Can you give me more suggestion?

Comment: You mean, suggestion on what to do in your situation?

Comment: Thank you. I changed the member function to static ...  let the lambda expression stateless

Comment: @Wuying283 This means you actually did not need `this` pointer, so this is a correct solution. If you are satisfied with the answer, consider accepting it.